# Javascript: How to put the backward slash character in its own string?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, string-literals

I have looked through similar questions to mine however, none helped with my problem.
I am creating a virtual keyboard for my wife to use in her classroom.

In the examples below, one way works where I add '4' to the TextArea while the other way with '' does not. It gives an error saying that there is an 'unterminated string literal'. I know it is because the backward slash character is special and is used for \n, \u, and others so Javascript is giving an error because of this. Is there any way to put the backward slash character in its own string with no spaces around it like this: ''? I am trying to add a \ to the TextArea.value. More specifically, when I press the \ button, a \ should be typed into the TextArea. Every other character on the keyboard works correctly except the backward slash. Any advice on how to accomplish this?

No Error:

```
TextArea.value += '4';
```

Error: 'unterminated string literal'

```
TextArea.value += '\';
```

Comment: `TextArea.value += '\';` -> `TextArea.value += '\\';`

Answer (score 2):

You can escape a backslash to enter a backslash:

```js
TextArea.value += '\\';
```